# Using VS 2012, project properties, Signing tab, upper section is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2012, properties

In my visual studio project, the upper part of the siging tab in the project's properties page is disabled.  How do I enable it?

image of this phenomenon
[image: click this link to see image of this phenomenon]

Answer (score 0):

The project properties which you are checking doesnt have Void Main (entry point).Hence,the checkbox (Sign the clickonce manifests) is disabled.Try to sign on the project which contains void main class.